# Shifting elements forward in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to do the following;
`[1,2,3,4]` -> `[1,1,2,3]`

Here is my attempt, but not working. I want to modify this in place.

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
temp = A[0]
for i in range(1, len(A)-2):
    A[i] = temp
    temp = A[i]
```

But instead I am getting back `[1,1,3,4]`. I want to do backward as well, but so far I can't shift by one forward.

Comment: One problem in your example is your `range`. `range(1, len(A)-2)` evaluates to `range(1,4-2)` so effectively `range(1, 2)`. The way python works, the last number in the range isn't looped over, so essentially your loop only executes once with i = 1. Also your logic in the loop is flawed as `temp = A[i]` will always contain the value in `A[0]` as that's what you've just set `A[i]` to in the line above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, perhaps some simple list slicing and assignment is all you need?

```
A[1:] = A[:-1]
A
# [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Similarly, shifting backward by 1 would be

```
A[:-1] = A[1:]
```

In general, to shift by N, use:

```
A[n:] = A[:-n]
```

---

Shifting forward by 1 can also be done with a `for` loop and a temp variable:

```
temp = A[0]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    temp, A[i+1] = A[i+1], temp

A
# [1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'd like to see how it can work using a for/while loop approach :( is that easily done? Sorry, new to programming.

Comment: @c1234 Hmm, okay. Take a look now.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: @c1234: Hopefully, following cs95's update, you can plainly see why using slice assignments would be a much better approach...